# Is there a way to add a PHP drop down menu for all items in an HTML table generated from an SQL query and take all changes at once?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have some PHP code that creates a table from an SQL query. What I'm attempting to do is make it so that for each row in the table under the SO column, a drop down menu is added with the ability to select from a list of names.

I have the dropdown menus in the table, however I'm only able to get the name selected actually added to the SQL table if I hit the submit query button next to each individual entry. I'm  trying to get it so I can just hit a single button and take the selected data from the drop downs all at the same time instead of individually.

Below is the code that makes my table.

```
<?php
              echo "<tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>SO</th><th>POS</th></tr>";
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)){
                echo "<tr><form action = addtoFix.php method=post>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['A']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['B']."</td>";
                echo "<td><select id='SO' name='soSelect'>
                          <option value='first'>Select...</option>
                          <option value='second'>Eric A</option>
                          <option value='third'>Hannibal B</option>
                          </select></td>"; 
                echo "<td>".$row['POS']."</td>";
                echo "<td><input type=submit></td>";
                echo "</form></tr>"; 
              }
              ?>
```

Below this is the sql statement from addtoFix.php. It is inside of a  block.

```
$sql1="insert into toFixTable(A, B, C, D, SO, E, F) values ($_POST[A],                      $_POST[B], '', '', '$_POST[SO]', '', '$_POST[F]')";
if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql1)){
echo " Data moved"; 
}else{
" Data not found/Query Failed";
}
```

I'm looking to get it so that the data set by soSelect is sent via post to addToFix all at once on a single button press, rather than having to press each submit button individually.

Comment: At a minimum you'll need to: 1. Change your dropdown names to ``soSelect[]`` (i.e. with square brackets at the end). This will cause ``$_POST['soSelect']`` to be an array of all the dropdown values. 2. Then change your code to produce a single ``<form>...</form>`` rather than one for each row.